# Bloquear o botão do timepicker

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados

```html
<?php
include('ligabd.php');
$id=$_GET["id"];
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["id_cliente"])){
 
}else{
 header("location:login.php",  true,  301 );
}
$successMsg='';

$consulta = 'SELECT * FROM marcacoes';
$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cliente='$id'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($ligabd,$consulta2);
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
 
$target_dir = "imagens_clientes/"; 
$thisimage1 = "imagem";
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$thisimage1]['tmp_name'])) {
 

                  $filename = $_FILES[$thisimage1]["name"];
                        $file_basename = substr($filename, 0,
strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
                        $file_ext = substr($filename,
strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
        //$ficheiro_nome = "doc_" . $id . "" . $file_ext;

  //$ficheiro_nome = $_FILES[$thisimage1]['name'];
  $temporario = $_FILES[$thisimage1]['tmp_name'];
  $destino = $target_dir .  $filename;
  if(!move_uploaded_file($temporario, $destino)) {
      // $msgInserirNoticiaNeg = $msgInserirNoticiaNeg . "<P
       
   
          }
            }
   
 


      
      $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($ligabd,$_POST['nome']);
      $image = $thisimage1;
     // $contacto = mysqli_real_escape_string($ligabd,$_POST['contacto']);
   $sugestoes = mysqli_real_escape_string($ligabd,$_POST['sugestoes']);
   $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($ligabd,$_POST['data']);
   $hora = mysqli_real_escape_string($ligabd,$_POST['horario']);
   
   $fim = date("H:i",strtotime(" $hora + 60 minutes"));
   
   
   
   
   $cont=0;   
$query = "SELECT * FROM marcacoes";
$result = $ligabd->query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
if ($row['data']==$data && $row['hora']==$hora){
 $cont=1;
 $successMsg='<font color="#ec1c24">Não é possível efetuar a marcação neste horário.</font>';
}
}

if ($cont==0){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO marcacoes (nome, imagem,sugestoes,data,hora,fim)
   VALUES ('$title', '$destino', '$sugestoes','$data','$hora','$fim')";
   $ligabd->query($sql);
   echo ($ligabd->error);
 $successMsg='<font color="#0ed145">Marcação efetuada com sucesso.</font>';  
   
 
}
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<link href='CSS/estilos.css' rel='stylesheet' media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#calendario" ).datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  beforeShowDay:
 function(dt){
  return [dt.getDay() == 0 ? false : true];
 },
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']});
});
    $( function() {
        $("#horario").timepicker({
            timeFormat    : 'HH:mm',
            interval: 60,
            minTime       : '08:00',
            maxTime       : '17:00',
            defaultTime   : '',
            startTime     : '08:00',
            dynamic       : false,
            modal         : true,
            scrollbar     : true});
    } );
 
 
 
</script>



<title>
Agendamento
</title>
</head>
<body> 
 

<div class="content" id="content">
<a href="logout2.php" class="linkbotao" style="position:relative;top:-20px;left:85%;">
Logout
</a>
<form action="pagina_marcacoes.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form" >
<a href="pagina_principal.php"><img src="imagens/logo.png" class="img"></a>
<p style="position: relative;left:22%;color:#fecb1d;" >AGENDAMENTO</p>

<?php while ($dado = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
  Nome:<input type="text" name="nome" class="input" value="<?php echo $dado["nome"]; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>


 
 <br>
  <p>Data:<input type="text" id="calendario" name="data" autocomplete="off" class="input" readonly /></p>
  <div>
                
                        
              <p>Hora:<input type="text" id="horario" name="horario" autocomplete="off" class="input" readonly /></p>
                   
                    </div>
                    
 <br>
 Sugestões:<input type="text" name="sugestoes" maxlength="500" class="input">
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="file" name="imagem" style="border-radius:15px;">
 <br>
 <br>
 <button name="send" id="login" class="btn">
       Efetuar marcação
      </button>
 <br>
 <?php echo $successMsg;?>
 </form>
 </div>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Bom dia,

Será que alguém me pode ajudar?

Tenho um datePicker e um timePicker e queria que quando clicasse numa data do datePicker ele me bloqueasse uma hora do timePicker que já esteja inserida na base de dados nesse mesmo dia ao invés de me dar um aviso após clicar no botão para enviar os dados para a base de dados.

Acham que é muito complicado?

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Adiciona seu a url da documentação do timepicker que você está usando. Adiciona também a estrutura do seu banco.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258036/datepicker-timepicker-selecionar-hor%C3%A1rio-de-acordo-com-o-dia-da-semana-jquery-e  foi onde fui buscar o datepicker e o time picker e a minha tabela da base de dados é composta pelo id_marcacao, nome, data, hora, fim(hora final), imagens e sugestoes.

Comment: Acha que me consegue ajudar? Estava a precisar de saber.

Comment: As informações que vc deu não são suficientes pra tentar reproduzir o problema... Existem muitos plugins de timepicker, você pode testa-los ao invés de pegar um script aleatório sem nenhuma documentação como pegou da pergunta de outro cara.